# PHP imagick convert svg to image issue

Tags: php, imagick, image-size

I was not able to figure out why I am not able to do the conversion from svg to image.

System:

```
Windows 2008 Server
II7
PHP 5.3.10-      Imagick is installed
```

Code

```
$command = 'C:\imagemagick\convert.exe d:\path-to-svg-file\sample.svg d:\path-to-output-folder\sample.png 2>&1';

exec($command, $output);
```

ERROR

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(102) "convert.exe: Must specify image size `C:/Windows/TEMP/magick-PY5hNkFu' @ error/mvg.c/ReadMVGImage/185."
    [1]=> string(126) "convert.exe: no images defined `d:\inetpub\...\output\sample.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Specify Size :

```
convert -size 568x604 d:\tiger.svg d:\tiger.jpg
```

What about SVG to other image formats

```
 convert file.svg file.png
```

**I tried converting to a PNG but had the same problem as with JPGs**

Comment: C:\imagemagick\..\convert.exe -size 400x200 "d:\inetpub\...\svg\sample.svg" "d:\inetpub\...\sample.png" I have added the size and that error is gone but now I am getting an empty image(sample.png 1kb).

Comment: Can you paste your command here so i can check that whats wrong?

Comment: 'C:\imagemagick\convert.exe -size 300x300 "d:\inetpub\path-to-svg-file\sample.svg" "d:\inetpub\path-to-output-flderg\output\sample.png"'

Comment: you were not using proper hyphens, possible long or short hyphens rather than normal hyphens (at least that is what I found when I cut and pasted your command)

Comment: I have used yours 'convert -size 300x300 svg/sample1.svg output/sample.png' ...still outputs same blank 300 by 300 png file.

Comment: tried to convert it to jpg,gif and the same 1kb blank image gets generated

Comment: Gradient support is not complete in ImageMagick. Are you running under Linux? If so, download / install the very latest ImageMagick release, 6.4.9-4 and it should fix the problem. If you are running under Windows, it will not render properly.

Comment: yes I am running it on windows but it is not even converting a simple svg that only draws a rectangle. FYI: now I am able to convert using exec from php but still is not able to get the imagick class working.

Comment: Try this:

    sudo port install ImageMagick +rsvg
    convert image.svg image.png

Answer (score 0):

svg images are vectors. They have no inherent size, simply directions on what lines to draw and where. imagemagic wants you tell you the size of the destination image, in pixels, that it should generate for you. should it make a 100x100 picture? a 999,999,999x999,999,999? None of that is included in the svg details, so you have to supply it.

Comment: Yes SVG is a vector graphics. But here is what is so confusing: One, the same code works from command line and also in my local machine it works when I run exec in php script(windows7, wamp server) and also works when I use imagick class to do the conversion. Two, svg in its parent node has a width and height and I think that is being used.